# Is the Los Pollos Hermanos eatery a real place or a movie set?

Tags: breaking-bad, film-location

In overall Breaking Bad series, only 2 of the eateries of Los Pollos Hermanos eateries were shown. One in which the main events happen and another one is within mall or commercial complex which is seen for just small time in one episode.

The eatery where most of the events take place, where Gus and Walter meet for the first time. Is it a real located eatery or is it just a set created for the series?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a real place in Albuquerque called "Twisters":

[image: Twisters]

> So many of Breaking Bad’s filming locations in Albuquerque, New Mexico
>   have become iconic and none more so than Twisters, which played home
>   to Gus Fring’s crystal meth front, Los Pollos Hermanos.

See [the source article](http://metro.co.uk/2013/02/26/a-breaking-bad-pilgrimage-to-twisters-the-real-los-pollos-hermanos-3515683/) for more information.

Comment: Los Pollos Hermanos could soon be [a real restaurant](http://www.eater.com/2015/5/1/8529509/breaking-bad-los-pollos-hermanos-real-restaurant-vince-gilligan)